# Importar datos de un excel a una base de datos con ASP. NET CORE 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, sql-server-2014

Mi html
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Mi ajax[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Mi controlador

```js
private IHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        public PrincipalController(IHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }
       
        public ActionResult OnPostImport()
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string folderName = "Upload";
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
            string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string sFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
                ISheet sheet;
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, file.FileName);
                using var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create);
                file.CopyTo(stream);
                stream.Position = 0;
                if (sFileExtension == ".xls")
                {
                    HSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream); //This will read the Excel 97-2000 formats  
                    sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); //get first sheet from workbook  
                }
                else
                {
                    XSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(stream); //This will read 2007 Excel format  
                    sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); //get first sheet from workbook   
                }
                IRow headerRow = sheet.GetRow(0); //Get Header Row
                int cellCount = headerRow.LastCellNum;
                sb.Append("<table class='table'><tr>");
                for (int j = 0; j < cellCount; j++)
                {
                    NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICell cell = headerRow.GetCell(j);
                    if (cell == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.ToString())) continue;
                    sb.Append("<th>" + cell.ToString() + "</th>");
                }
                sb.Append("</tr>");
                sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
                for (int i = (sheet.FirstRowNum + 1); i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++) //Read Excel File
                {
                    IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
                    if (row == null) continue;
                    if (row.Cells.All(d => d.CellType == CellType.Blank)) continue;
                    for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < cellCount; j++)
                    {
                        if (row.GetCell(j) != null)
                            sb.Append("<td>" + row.GetCell(j).ToString() + "</td>");
                    }
                    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
                }
                sb.Append("</table>");
            }
            return this.Content(sb.ToString());
        }
```

Buenas tardes comunidad,
Estoy tratando de importar datos de un excel a una base de datos, estoy trabajando con asp.net core 3.1 , 
Agregue el controlador, ajax y vista. En este punto ya me lee el excel pero lo que ahora tengo que hacer es que inserte los datos leidos al sqlserver. Como podría realizar esto?. Le agradecería que me ayuden con esto.

Comment: @fredyfx ya agregue la vista me podrías ayudar ?

Comment: Claro, primero reemplaza el `HttpPostedFileBase` por `List<IFormFile>` y dime si te genera algún error

Comment: El error que me sale ahora es List<IFormFile>" no contiene una definición para "ContentLength" ni un método de extensión accesible @fredyfx

Comment: ¿qué opciones te salen cuando tipeas `file.` y dejas el autocompletar?

Comment: Con auto completar count reemplaza a ContentLength, pero tengo varios errores mas y no se solucionan con el autocompletar. @fredyfx añadi una foto para que pueda ver

Comment: Ya pude leer el excel, como podrias insertar los datos leido al sqlserver ? @fredyfx

Comment: Edita la pregunta, serás el héroe de más usuarios que experimentan el mismo problema. Si usas Entity Framework, haces un `mapping` de los campos de tu tabla con una clase y le das SaveChanges() a la lista entera de filas que tienes en el DT. Si usas ADO .net, podrías hacer algo parecido, ¿cuál tecnología conoces y/o estás usando?

Comment: Ya agregue el controlador y ajax con el que me lee el excel. Me podrias ayudar a registrar estos datos en sqlserver. Gracias de ante mano @fredyfx

Comment: Puedes usar la libreria SpreadsheetLight para leer el excel y hacer querys con adonet o entityframework si prefieres.